# Restricting access to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I work on a project involving user addons where sessionStorage should not be accessible by any other script than my own. Most of the user scripts run inside a worker already, but some have to run outside because of DOM access. I'm using this script to create a fake sessionStorage after I have read my data:

```
const Storage = Object.create(self.Storage.prototype);
Object.defineProperty(Storage, 'setItem', {
    value: function (key, value) {
        Storage[key] = value;
    },
});
Object.defineProperty(Storage, 'getItem', {
    value: function (key) {
        return Storage[key];
    },
});
Object.defineProperty(Storage, 'removeItem', {
    value: function (key) {
        delete Storage[key];
    },
});
Object.defineProperty(Storage, 'clear', {
    value: function () {
        Object.keys(Storage).forEach(key => delete Storage[key]);
    },
});
Object.defineProperty(Storage, 'key', {
    value: function (i) {
        return Object.keys(Storage)[i];
    },
});
Object.defineProperty(Storage, 'length', {
    get: function () {
        return Object.values(Storage).length;
    },
});
Object.defineProperty(self, 'sessionStorage', {
    value: Storage,
    writable: false,
});
```

It behaves just like the original sessionStorage. The question is, would there be a way to restore it to the original sessionStorage for someone else running a script on the page after my script has run?

Another way i see is calling, but I'm afraid that it would break execution of other scripts.

```
delete window.sessionStorage
```

Comment: Even if you `delete window.sessionStorage`, a user script would be able to create an `<iframe>` element with `document.createElement("iframe")` and extract that iframe's `window` attribute, which would allow them to get a new copy of `window.sessionStorage`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I can disable window popus with the CSP header `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts, frame-src none, frame-ancestors none` and  iframes with `Object.defineProperty(HTMLIFrameElement.prototype, 'contentWindow'|'contentDocument',` and `delete window.frames`. Can you still answer my initial question if such a redefinition with Object.defineProperty could be reverted?